# How to modify Authorization Rules (URL authorization) in IIS using Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, authorization

Is there a way to modify the Authorization Rules for URL's in IIS (8.0) using Powershell?

I have seen a lot solutions for .NET and FTP, but not really for IIS.
Like for ftp.

```powershell
Import-Module WebAdministration
Add-WebConfiguration -Filter /System.FtpServer/Security/Authorization -Value (@{AccessType="Allow"; Users="$FTPUsername"; Permissions="Read, Write"}) -PSPath IIS: -Location "Default FTP Site/$FTPUserDir/$FTPUsername"
```

Also the help function in powershell is not really helpful.

Comment: Did you know how to clear or remove rules? Adding is ok, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```powershell
Add-WebConfiguration -Filter /system.webServer/security/authorization -Value (@{AccessType="Allow"; Users="$IISUsername"; Permissions="Read, Write"}) -PSPath IIS: -Location "Your IIS Site"
```

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used this to add a user to the Authorization Rule of the web server itself (not a site):

```
Add-WebConfiguration -Filter "/system.webServer/security/authorization" -Value @{accessType="Allow"; users="xxx"; verbs="xxx"}
```